# Eclipse STS content assist works for java but not groovy

Tags: eclipse, groovy, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I have a groovy project in STS Eclipse 3.7. When I hit ctrl+space, I get content assist in my java files, however I do not get anything in my Groovy files.

What do I need to set in order for this to work?

Comment: Use an IDE with better groovy support? IntelliJ community edition for example

Comment: I'd love to try that, but unfortunately I'm in a corporate environment and don't have the luxury of changing my IDE :/

Comment: So they let you use a language, but won't give you suitable tools?

Comment: hahaha! Welcome to corporate America :)

Comment: there is groovy language support out there for Eclipse and you can install that into STS, too. But you need to make sure you pick the right version for your installation. Do you use the STS distribution? What exact version? And what is the Eclipse version behind it? (the about dialog reveals all that)

Comment: Version: 3.7.2.RELEASE
Build Id: 201511261048
Platform: Eclipse Mars.1 (4.5.1)